# How to give opacity to multiple background images separately

Tags: css

I am working with Extjs and want to apply css (opacity) like below but it is not working plz help me out

```
  .class{
    background-image:url(../images/marion.png),url(../images/dots1.png),url(../images/dots2.png),url(../images/neur        al.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat-x,repeat-x,no-repeat;
    background-position: center 22px,right center,right center,0 0 ; 
    background-size :42% 9%,20% 15%,20% 12%,100% 100% ;
    opacity:0.3,0.2,0.2,0.8; /* this is not working */
}
```

Comment: I've never seen any CSS like that....

Comment: `Opacity` does not take multiple values. CSS backgrounds do not provide the ability you are asking.

Comment: everything is working fine if i give opacity : .2; but it will be applied to all background images

Comment: If you know the pixel coordinates of all your images AND the color behind your images you can write an extremely long `box-shadow` property with lots of comma separated values to create overlays on each of your backgrounds to create the illusion of opacity, but I doubt that will be worth it for you.

Comment: You can only give one value with opacity. If you try to set multiple comma separated opacities the property becomes invalid and the browser will ignore it.

Comment: Zaqx .. could you please give any example for box-shadow property

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is that CSS can’t do this. However, since you asked for an example I’ll give it to you.

Again I highly highly doubt this is worth it for you but if you do know the pixel coordinates of all your background-images AND the background behind your background-images you can write an extremely long box-shadow property that essentially draws blocks of colored pixels over the areas you need to create the illusion of opacity.

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/nofowo/4/edit?css,output

You can delete the `figure::before { }` block to see where the illusion of opacity was being applied.

```
figure {
    width: 400px;
    height: 440px;

    background-image: 
      url('http://40.media.tumblr.com/9156a139784c4fde141fc379c7b5973d/tumblr_ngasc7M0dA1qhhnbao1_1280.jpg'),
      url('http://36.media.tumblr.com/c1d431544107b313e5b2406b10387ccc/tumblr_ng6erxjLOp1qhhnbao1_1280.jpg'),
      url('http://36.media.tumblr.com/f375f4052fff1849aa754a8df2d320a7/tumblr_nfzmz0Ckfe1qhhnbao1_1280.jpg'),
      url('http://40.media.tumblr.com/801f19fea89afccb5f45d481a9399afa/tumblr_nfxteea7ss1qhhnbao1_1280.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 22px, right center, right center, 0 0; 
    background-size: 42% 9%, 20% 15%, 20% 12%, 100% 100%;
}

figure::before {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -49px;
    left: 44px;

    box-shadow: 
      70px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      80px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      90px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      100px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      110px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      120px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      130px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      140px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      150px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      160px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      170px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      180px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      190px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      200px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      210px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      220px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      230px 70px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      70px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      80px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      90px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      100px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      110px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      120px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      130px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      140px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      150px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      160px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      170px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      180px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      190px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      200px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      210px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      220px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      230px 80px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      70px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      80px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      90px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      100px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      110px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      120px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      130px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      140px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      150px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      160px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      170px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      180px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      190px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      200px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      210px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      220px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      230px 90px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      70px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      80px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      90px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      100px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      110px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      120px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      130px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      140px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      150px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      160px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      170px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      180px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      190px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      200px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      210px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      220px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6),
      230px 100px rgba(15,69,63,0.6);
}
```